# Raku pop() order of execution

Tags: raku

Isn't order of execution generally from left to right in Raku?

```
my @a = my @b = [9 , 3];
say (@a[1] - @a[0]) == (@b[1] R- @b[0]); # False {as expected}
say (@a.pop() - @a.pop()) == (@b.pop() R- @b.pop()); # True {Huh?!?}
```

This is what I get in Rakudo(tm) v2020.12 and 2021.07.
The first 2 lines make sense, but the third I can not fathom.

Answer (score 6):

It is.

But you should realize that the minus infix operator is just a subroutine under the hood, taking 2 parameters that are evaluated left to right.  So when you're saying:

```
$a - $b
```

you are in fact calling the `infix:<->` sub:

```
infix:<->($a,$b);
```

The `R` meta-operator basically creates a [wrap](https://docs.raku.org/routine/wrap) around the `infix:<->` sub that reverses the arguments:

```
my &infix:<R->($a,$b) = &infix:<->.wrap: -> $a, $b { nextwith $b, $a }
```

So, if you do a:

```
$a R- $b
```

you are in fact doing a:

```
infix:<R->($a,$b)
```

which is then basically a:

```
infix:<->($b,$a)
```

Note that in the call to `infix:<R->` in your example, `$a` become `3`, and `$b` becomes `9` because the order of the arguments is processed left to right.  This then calls `infix:<->(3,9)`, producing the `-6` value that you would also get without the `R`.

It may be a little counter-intuitive, but I consider this behaviour as correct.  Although the [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-R_reverse_metaoperator) could probably use some additional explanation on this behaviour.

Comment: But, my confusion is that subtraction is not commutative, there for `$a-$b` should `!=$b-$a` given 9 and 3. Yet in line 3 of my code, it does! And it only happens when the values are pop(), not when directly addressed as in line 2.

Comment: Upon further consideration...Your saying raku is swapping the functions first, then calling them.  Not swapping the results after the call.   Interesting...un-intuitive but interesting.

Comment: "Not swapping the results after the call." I'm confused about what you are suggesting. I've rewritten my answer. Does it make sense to you? What am I missing?

Comment: infix:<R->($b.pop(), $b.pop()) becomes infix:<->($b.pop(), $b.pop()).  I think I get it.

Comment: You seem to have a sign error (and/or a mistake in the argument order) in your second-to-last paragraph. If it worked as you currently describe ("`$a` become `3`, and `$b` becomes `9`"), then the result of `@b.pop() R- @b.pop()` would be `infix:<->($b,$a)` = `infix:<->(9,3)` = `6`, not `-6`.

Answer (score 5):

Let me emulate what I assumed was happening in line 3 of my code prefaced with @a is the same as @b is 9, 3 (big number then little number)

```
(@a.pop() - @a.pop()) == (@b.pop() R- @b.pop())
(3 - 9) == (3 R- 9)
( -6 ) == ( 6 )
False
```

...That was my expectation.  But what raku seems to be doing is

```
(@a.pop() - @a.pop()) == (@b.pop() R- @b.pop())
#R meta-op swaps 1st `@b.pop()` with 2nd `@b.pop()`
(@a.pop() - @a.pop()) == (@b.pop() - @b.pop()) 
(3 - 9) == (3 - 9)
( -6 ) == ( -6 )
True
```

The R in R- swaps functions first, then calls the for values.  Since they are the same function, the R in R- has no practical effect.

Side Note:  In fuctional programming a 'pure' function will return the same value every time you call it with the same parameters.  But pop is not 'pure'.  Every call can produce different results.  It needs to be used with care.

Comment: "The `R` in `R-` swaps functions first, then calls for the values." Just to clarify, it just does a simple source transform, swapping *the operands*, so `a Rop b` becomes `b op a`. The rest then naturally follows: Raku evaluates operands left to right, so `b` first, `a` second, and then, last of all, calls the function (which now has reversed and already evaluated operands. so `b op a`, with `b` and `a` already evaluated). And, in your Q, `a` and `b` are the same, so the `R` has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

The `R` meta op not only reverses the operator, it will also reverse the order in which the operands will be evaluated.

```raku
sub term:<a> { say 'a'; '3' }
sub term:<b> { say 'b'; '9' }

say a ~ b;
```

```
a
b
ab
```

Note that `a` happened first.

If we use `R`, then `b` happens first instead.

```raku
say a R~ b;
```

```
b
a
ba
```

---

The problem is that in your code all of the `pop` calls are getting their data from the same source.

```raku
my @data = < a b a b >;

sub term:<l> { my $v = @data.shift; say "l=$v"; return $v }
sub term:<r> { my $v = @data.shift; say "r=$v"; return $v }

say l ~ r;
```

```
l=a
r=b
ab
```

```raku
say l R~ r;
```

```
r=a
l=b
ab
```

---

A way to get around that is to use the reduce meta operator with a list

```raku
[-](@a.pop, @a.pop) == [R-](@a.pop, @a.pop)
```

Or in some other way make sure the `pop` operations happen in the order you expect.

You could also just use the values directly from the array without using `pop`.

```raku
[-]( @a[0,1] ) == [R-]( @a[2,3] )
```

Comment: "reduce meta operator", I gotta look that up. Thanks

Comment: "The `R` meta op not only reverses the operator, it reverses which side of the operator happens first." Some readers might interpret that to mean `R` is somehow doing *two* reverses, not one. But it just does *one* reverse. The `R` meta op does not reverse the *operator* (the `-`), it reverses the as yet unevaluated *operands* (the two `@b.pop()`s). Then, when the modified *operation* is then evaluated, it turns out, in this instance, that the reversal makes no difference, because the unevaluated operands are exactly the same (they're both `@b.pop()`).

Answer (score 3):

Let me emulate what happens by writing the logic one way for `@a` then *manually* reversing the operands for `@b` instead of using `R`:

```
my @a = my @b = [9 , 3];
sub apop { @a.pop }
sub bpop { @b.pop }

say apop - apop; # -6
say bpop - bpop; # -6  (operands *manually* reversed)
```

This not only appeals to my sense of intuition about what's going on, I'm thus far confused why you were confused and why Liz has said "It may be a little counter-intuitive" and you've said it is plain *un*intuitive!